# IOException occur during playing song from mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, ioexception

I want to play a song from Android MediaStore. I know that  id 1834 is absolutely correctly.. while debugging i found that at
`mp.prepare();` `IOException occurs`. How can i solve this.

```
prevSong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                try 
                {
                    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

                    Uri fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 1834);

                    mp.setDataSource(context, fileUri);

                  //  mMediaPlayer.reset();

                //    mp.setDataSource(context, uri);    

                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();

                    mp.start();

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (SecurityException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated the "status" reported by IOE. Can you give logs?

Did you have the external storage permission in the manifest?

Also, it looks like your skip next/previous events are creating a new media player every time. If I were you, I would have one media manager which handles play, stop, next, prev. And UI events call this one media manager. The media manager would take care of proper closure of open MediaPlayer object when taking on another task such as skip previous.

Comment: yes i have   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in Manifest. I only want to play that songs other work is done by me as you said